# Create array key from value. i have created array define to bellow.i have differentiate actual result and expected result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Actual Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sub_id] => 3
            [sub_name] => tttt
            [master_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sub_id] => 4
            [sub_name] => yyyy
            [master_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sub_id] => 5
            [sub_name] => kkkk
            [master_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Expected Result

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array(
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [sub_id] => 3
                    [sub_name] => tttt
                    [master_id] => 3
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [sub_id] => 4
                    [sub_name] => yyyy
                    [master_id] => 3
                )
        )
    [4] => Array(
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [sub_id] => 5
                    [sub_name] => kkkk
                    [master_id] => 4
                )    
        )
)
```

Comment: Kindly post some of your code then only we can help you.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: actual array is my result. in actual array master id is same so as per expection i want to create array having key of master id

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new array and set value of master id as the index and put the value in it.

```
$data = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $data[$value['master_id']][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer and get reputation points for both of us

Answer (score 1):

```
$actualArray = array(array('sub_id' => 3, 'sub_name' => 'tttt', 'master_id' => 3),array('sub_id' => 4, 'sub_name' => 'yyyy', 'master_id' => 3),array('sub_id' => 5, 'sub_name' => 'kkkk', 'master_id' => 4));
$tempArray = array_unique(array_column($actualArray, 'master_id'));
$uniqueArray = array_intersect_key($actualArray, $tempArray);

foreach ($uniqueArray as $key => $masters) {
    $count    = 0;  
    foreach ($actualArray as $key1 => $actuals) {
        if($masters['master_id'] == $actuals['master_id']){
            $expectedArray[$key][$count] = $actuals;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```